# Simplifying $\int_0^a \int_0^b \Bigl(\sum_{m} \sum_{n}\dot{A}_{mn} \sin\frac{m \pi x}{a} \sin\frac{n \pi y}{b}\Bigr)^2dy \,dx$

Tags: integration, summation

I am currently working on a small thesis for my university. A part of the thesis is to derive a formula for the kinetic energy of a rectangular plate $(a,b)$.
For a single particle, the kinetic energy equals:
$$T = \dfrac{1}{2} m v^2$$
For the plate I am dealing with, I only have the deflection $w$ which is expressed as a double sum where $A_{mn}$ is unknown
$$w(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_{mn} \cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{m \pi x}{a}\right) \cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{n \pi y}{b}\right)$$
The kinetic energy then becomes:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 T &= \dfrac{1}{2} \rho h \int_0^a \int_0^b \left(\frac{d}{dt}w(x)\right)^2dy \ dx \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} \rho h \int_0^a \int_0^b \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dot{A}_{mn} \cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{m \pi x}{a}\right) \cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{n \pi y}{b}\right)\right)^2dy \ dx
\end{aligned}
$$
This is where I got stuck. I have no idea on how to tackle an integral like this.
I was looking into the Cauchy product but I don't know how to apply it to more than one sum.

I know that the result is going to be something like:
$$T = ... \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dot{A}_{mn}^2$$
where $...$ are only a few constants.

I am very happy if someone could help me solving this integral!

Greetings,

Comment: You have to expand $(\sum_m\sum_n...)^2$ to remove the square and then compute the integrals, many  of which vanish...

Comment: I tried to remove it using the Cauchy product but didn’t get far

Comment: Mhm Okay I get what you mean.

It results in $a_{11}^2 + a_{12}^2 + a_{21}^2$ ... together with:

$2 * a_{11} * (all other a) + a_{12} * (all other a) + ...$ but i dont know how to write that second one in general form which doesnt include 4 sum signs.

Comment: I did that. The result is:


$a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2 + 2 (a_{11} (a_{12}+a_{21}+a_{22}) + a_{12} (a_{21}, a_{22}) + a_{21} (a_{22})) $

The first part with the squares is very simple to put into the sums. But I dont see a good solution to express the second part except using 4 sums

Comment: Thats what I have written

Comment: I have also said that before. We got the sum of the squares like that but that other part can only be represented using 4 sums

Comment: and then what happens with the double integrals in the double and quadruple sums?

Comment: Well I guess it will vanish for the right side but i cant see why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to simplify, let us assign an integer $q$ to every pair of integers $(m,n)$. As a consequence, $$\sum_m\sum_n A_{mn}=\sum_q A_q$$ (with an abuse of notations here). We can say without much difficulty that $$\left(\sum_qA_q\right)^2=\sum_qA^2_q+2\sum_q\sum_{p\neq q}A_qA_p$$ Back to the initial notations, the double sum of the squared terms reads $$\frac{1}{2}\rho h \sum_m\sum_n \dot{A}^2_{mn}\int_0^a\sin^2\left(\frac{m\pi x}{a}\right)\int_0^b\sin^2\left(\frac{n\pi y}{b}\right)=\frac{1}{8}\rho h a b\sum_m\sum_n \dot{A}^2_{mn}\tag{1}$$
The double sum in $(q,p)$ is actually a quadruple sum of the form $$\frac{1}{2}\rho h \sum_m\sum_n\sum_i\sum_j \dot{A}_{mn}\dot{A}_{ij}\int_0^a\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{i\pi x}{a}\right)\int_0^b\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{b}\right)\sin\left(\frac{j\pi y}{b}\right)\tag{2}$$ with either $m\neq i$ and/or $n\neq j$ since $q\neq p$. In other words, one of the integrals in (2) always vanish and the kinetic energy is given by (1).

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn’t see how it cancels out but this is very clear!